# Should we have separate tags for the Soyuz launcher and the Soyuz spacecraft?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Right now, the [soyuz](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz) tag refers specifically to "questions regarding the Soyuz manned spacecraft"; it doesn't include questions about the Soyuz launcher. Should we create separate tags for the Soyuz spacecraft and the Soyuz launcher, or should we edit the description of [soyuz](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz) to include both?

Sample questions about the Soyuz launcher:

- [Is Soyuz-2.1v as hardy as previous Soyuz
  launchers?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20279/is-soyuz-2-1v-as-hardy-as-previous-soyuz-launchers)
- [What is different from the R-7 that launched Sputnik, to the Soyuz
  launcher used for Soyuz/Progress
  launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/what-is-different-from-the-r-7-that-launched-sputnik-to-the-soyuz-launcher-used?rq=1)
- [What is the flyaway cost of a Soyuz and Proton
  Rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/what-is-the-flyaway-cost-of-a-soyuz-and-proton-rocket?rq=1)
- [What do the various logos and text on the R-7 Soyuz
  mean?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/what-do-the-various-logos-and-text-on-the-r-7-soyuz-mean?rq=1)

Comment: I went ahead and executed the change in Suggestion #1 steps 1-2. I started working on retagging questions that needed [tag:soyuz-launcher], but I didn't have time to finish. Others may want to keep looking through [tag:soyuz-spacecraft] to see if any other retags are needed, and someone may want to write up the description and/or wiki for [tag:soyuz-launcher].

Comment: I went through everything with the soyuz-spacecraft tag and retagged them as needed.

Comment: Do we have an R-7 tag? Or Semyorka tag? If we did, those who are familiar with the Russian families of rockets will know to use if for Soyuz launcher. :-)

Comment: @DrZ214 We don't have either of those tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestion #1:

1. Create a [soyuz-spacecraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-spacecraft) tag and a [soyuz-launcher](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-launcher) tag.
2. Merge and synonymize [soyuz](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz) into [soyuz-spacecraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-spacecraft).
3. Retag some questions as [soyuz-launcher](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-launcher) as necessary.

I think [soyuz](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz) should be synonymous to [soyuz-spacecraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-spacecraft) because that is its most frequent use case. If someone is intending to tag a Soyuz launcher question, they or an editor should notice that [soyuz-spacecraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-spacecraft), when it pops up, is the wrong tag.

Comment: Marking this accepted, since the consensus seems clear.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion #2:

Redefine [soyuz](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz) to include both the spacecraft and launcher, since they are so closely related.

Comment: This seems likely to lead to more [confusion](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20276/so-with-soyuz-being-retired-what-gets-people-up-to-the-iss-and-back-down-now), not less, which would be unfortunate.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree